# Onelogin Configuring SSH PAM Module

Tags: onelogin

i have use case to integrate ssh session to onelogin, leverage VLDAP feature as authentication method. have read the guide from https://developers.onelogin.com/authentication/tools/linux-ssh-pam-module

but im still struggle to find the onepam.py and template-onepam.json.
[Guide Description][1]

could could help me to find those files
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHIzv.png

Comment: I think that these would have been installed by the `libpam-python` package that you were supposed to install.

"""
Let’s start by installing the dependencies for onepam (these are for apt, the names of packages may vary on other distributions).

sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y libpam-python
"""

If you haven't installed that package yet that's step 1. If you have then try searching your file system. I suggest checking /usr/lib and /usr/share/. Or let the machine do it. E.g., Slow, but full; append a pager/redirect if you expect many results. `find / -iname '*onepam*' 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Oh, sorry, no, ... That's a dependency. :) I would guess it's locked behind that Developers menu, but I have no experience with it. :\

Comment: Just stumbled over this question. 
I've created a pam/nss module for onelogin that could be used for integrating OneLogin on Linux servers. You can find it here, https://github.com/patchon/pam-onelogin 

It has quite a few benefits over the guide provided by the link you are referring to. Hope that helps.